# Facebook share counter not working on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I have facebook share counter on my website and it works correct,but on iOS Safari it doesn't show show number of shares. If I'm using incognito mode (private), it works correctly... Any suggestions?

```
 $.getJSON( 'http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://example.com', function( fbdata ) {
      $('#fb-count').text(fbdata.share.share_count)
 });
```

Even if I'll use simple `alert()` inside function it won't appear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a solution using PHP.

```
$fb = json_decode( file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/http://example.com') );
$shares = $fb->share->share_count;
```